# Race Condition Read Write

Tags: process, operating-system, synchronization, pthreads, race-condition

By definition a Race Condition happens when two different Processes try to change a shared variable simultaneously,  but does it happen even if one of them doesn't write when also the other writes?

Example:

`Process X; var.read -> var.change -> var.write
 Process Y; var.read -> var.change -> var.write`

`Process X; var.read -> var.change
 Process Y; var.read -> var.change -> var.write
 Process X; var.write`

Both should lead to inconsistency since a write happens when something else is happening, but should they both lead to a Race Condition?

Comment: This would depend on your model of computation, but for example C11 draft standard n1570 says: *5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races 4 Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.[...] 25 The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.*

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have a race condition with one writer and simultaneous readers.

Assume you want y to be greater than zero and have something like this:

```
GLOBAL X ;

if X > 100 then
   y := x - 50 ;
```

If someone else is writing to x, y could end up being less than zero.